# Solving for the steady state of a system

Tags: equation-solving

```
Solve[
  {δ*x + h0/(1 + z) - (δ + k)*ptot*x/(K1*(x/K1 + y/K2 + z/K3)) == 0, 
   δ*y + h0/(1 + x) - (δ + k)*ptot*y/(K2*(x/K1 + y/K2 + z/K3)) == 0, 
   δ*z + h0/(1 + y) - (δ + k)*ptot*z/(K3*(x/K1 + y/K2 + z/K3)) == 0},
  {x, y, z}]
```

This Mathematica code has been running for over 20 minutes now. I'm trying to solve for the steady state of a three-dimensional ODE model. Am I wrong in expecting Mathematica to solve this for me, or am I doing something else wrong?

The model I'm trying to solve for, written in proper LaTeX, looks like this:

[image]

where $i = 1, 2, 3$ and $H_1 = \frac{H_0}{1+ x_3}$, $H_2 = \frac{H_1}{1+ x_0}$, and $H_3 = \frac{H_2}{1+ x_2}$

Comment: The system of three equations probably can be combined into a single ninth-order polynomial, but it is unlikely that a closed-form solution exists.  Would a numerical solution do?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Thank you for replying, what I was trying to do was to find the steady state of the equations, but it did not succeed with my code. Thus, I wonder if there is any problems with my code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Simply stated, `Solve` and `Reduce` are unable to obtain solutions in a reasonable amount of time, because the expressions are fairly complicated.  Moreover, even if they could, the answers would be in terms of `Root` functions.  Ninth-order polynomial systems rarely have closed-form solutions.